# Graphics.h refresh screen

Tags: c++, graphics, header, bgi

I made a small program that displays a 3d cube that you can scale on any axis using the arrow keys. Only problem is that im using `cleardevice();` for refreshing the cube ( so that there is no "smearing" when scaling the cube ). that works fine its just that every time the cube refreshes using this method the screen goes black for a split second resulting in annoying flickering. Is there a better way of refreshing the screen every time the user changes the cube?
I did actually research this but i wasnt able to find anything suitable (Maybe im just bad at researching but i couldn't find anything for the live of me)

Comment: The thing you are looking for is "double buffering".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are 2 ways to handle this:

1. **Double buffering**

   I do not use **BGI** so I stick to their docs. for WinBGIm you can use

   - [int swapbuffers (void);](https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/doc/swapbuffers.html)

   On oldstyle **BGI** use this:

   ```
   int oldv = getvisualpage( );
   int olda = getactivepage( );
   setvisualpage(olda);
   setactivepage(oldv);
   ```
2. **use vertical synchronization with monitor**

   You need to wait for **VSync** before calling `cleardevice();`. On **DOS** you can use **VGA BIOS** or direct **VGA/VESA** access to obtain the signal. On higher **OS** you need to use some kind of gfx **API** or Driver **API** to get **VSync**.

   In both cases consult the documentation for target platform.